# Android Studio Service GPS Location error in background

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My idea is to perform an android service to send the GPS coordinates via volley to a web services.
Although the service works (since it executes the test tone) when the application is closed, the music continues but stops sending the coordinates to the web services.
Could someone guide me in what I am doing wrong?
I leave the code of the ActivityMain and the Services class
Thank you

```
public class GPSServices extends Service {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private MediaPlayer Player;
    private MediaPlayer player;

    public static String DNI = "222222";
    public static float en_Latitud;
    public static float en_Longitud;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service was Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        registrarLocalizacion();

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        // This will play the ringtone continuously until we stop the service.
        player.setLooping(true);
        // It will start the player
        player.start();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void registrarLocalizacion() {

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 8000, 0, new milocalizationListener());
    }
    private class milocalizationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }

            Location locDestino = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            en_Latitud = (float) location.getLatitude();
            en_Longitud = (float) location.getLongitude();
            guardarGps();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stopping the player when service is destroyed
        player.stop();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void guardarGps(){

        //seteamos la fecha actual
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS");
        final String InFecha = sdf.format(new Date());



        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Http.URL_WEB_SERVICE + "insertar.php",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject objResultado = new JSONObject(response);
                            String estadox = objResultado.get("estado").toString();
                            /*if(!estadox.contains("exito")){
                                //  if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase("exito")){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hubo un error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Coordenadas Registradas", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }*/
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid conexion", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("DNI", DNI );
                params.put("Fecha", InFecha);
                params.put("Latitud", String.valueOf(en_Latitud));
                params.put("Longitud", String.valueOf(en_Longitud));
                // params.put("direccion",distancia.getText().toString().trim());
                // params.put("coordenadas",latitud.getText().toString().trim());
                // params.put("lon",longitud.getText().toString().trim());
                return params;

            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);

    }
}
```

Comment: please mention logcats

Comment: You need a foreground service.  Background services are limited to 2-3 minutes when your activity is not in the foreground